# Creating UI in QT/QML using 1 image with all states of UI control

Tags: image, user-interface, qml

I am looking to create a new QML control using PNG images.  I would normally use 1 image for each state (Example hover, clicked, disabled).  I have noticed that some developers use 1 image with all states of the control in 1 image.. like this...

[image]

I would like to learn how to use images like these, I imagine it's useful for creating different styles by modifying a template of a unique design.

So my question is how to use an image and only show one state at a time?

Here is a sample image to use.  I would like to create a simple bullet image in QML that does the following.

1. Never clicked show grey,
2. Hovered it shows yellow,
3. Clicked it shows orange.

Here is the image to use.

[image]

What I can't figure out is how to use only part of the image per state.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet might be to use [`QQuickImageProvider`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qquickimageprovider.html) for this. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43193300/904422)'s an example that shows how to subclass it. You could probably also do it with a shader like mentioned in the other answer on that page.

If you want an easier way to achieve your original workflow of using one image per state, you should check out the [Imagine style](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-imagine.html#detailed-desc-imagine).